# Static file is not opening in Django project-- error 404 1825?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I am constantly getting 404 error when my page is trying to load static image file.

ERROR:

[12/Aug/2022 12:02:54] "GET /myApp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 370
[12/Aug/2022 12:02:54] "GET /static/myApp/images/cofee.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1825

SETTINGS:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
my_templates = Path(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
static_dir = Path(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    static_dir, 
]
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    {% load static %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>We are here to Help</h1>
    <img src="{% static 'myApp/images/cofee.jpg' %}" alt= " no show ">
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: server is running without error and page is loading just fine with heading1 showing but static image is not showing.

Comment: You can also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73310157/17562044) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your setting and first import os like:

```
import os
```

and use this code as well:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Add these new lines
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'YourAppName/static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Comment: [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATIC_ROOT) is used in deployment.

Comment: Thanks for reply my code was correct actually there was a typing error in the image file name. Latest Django version does't need os.path.join, it's much simpler.